# A bug in my sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am developing a phonebook application on PHP. After typing 3 characters, the search script is fired. This query works well. But I have discovered that if I enter the search box `%%%` characters the page lists all the records which I do not want it to do.

```
$value = "%" . $_POST['value']  .  "%";
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT
                           k.id, 
                           k.name, 
                           k.surname, 
                           k.phone, 
                           k.email, 
                           u.title, 
                           g.job,
                           b.dept
                      FROM 
                           persons k
                           JOIN titles u ON k.title_id = u.id
                           JOIN departments b ON k.dept_id = b.id
                           JOIN jobs g ON k.job_id = g.id
                      WHERE
                           active = 1 AND
                          ( 
                            LOWER(k.name) LIKE :v1 OR
                            LOWER(k.surname) LIKE :v2 OR
                            LOWER(k.phone) LIKE :v3 OR
                            LOWER(k.email) LIKE :v4
                          )
                      ORDER BY
                          dept, 
                          name, 
                          surname"
            );

$query->bindValue(":v1", strtolower($value), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":v2", strtolower($value), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":v3", strtolower($value), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":v4", strtolower($value), PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
```

How can I prevent this bug?

Comment: Don't allow special chars.

Comment: It's not a bug, rather a feature of using `like`.  Strip `%` from user input, and put it where you want in `$value`.

Comment: if I do `$value = "%" . str_replace("%","", $_POST["value"]) . "%";` I think this will make a sense.

Comment: Be careful though, you may want to validate that `value` still has 3+ characters in it after stripping the `%`, otherwise the effect would be the same. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate the users input before executing the query.

something like this should work:

`$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);`

Comment: `$value = "%" . preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/","", $_POST["value"]) . "%";`

Comment: While the idea is sound, careful using that _specific_ replacement, it's not so good on email addresses, and will even damage names like O'Riley and such. You'd be better off blacklisting characters special to `like` rather than trying to whitelist an inadequate set.

Comment: Actually I separated the email address into two fields (before and after `@` character). So it is not a problem for me.

Comment: @Özkan, `@` is _not_ the only character you need to worry about in email addresses (or even names, if you read my previous comment). You'll run into fewer problems with a blacklist method.

Answer (score 3):

Disallow (or remove) the entry of those characters special to `like`, such as `%` and add it to the string when you bind the parameters, such as:

```
$query->bindValue(":v1", strtolower($value) . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

or:

```
$val2 = strtolower($value) . "%";
$query->bindValue(":v1", $val2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

That's probably the easiest solution.

Comment: With how many times the same `$value` is bound, I would say to append the `%` to the actual `$value` instead of in each `bindValue()`

Comment: Should not `+` be `.` or am I learning a new string operator?

Comment: @paxdiablo Sorry, I always try and optimize code that I see >< But the idea was correct and worked. =D